# UV/Image Editor - renders both cameras... depending. Is this normal behaviour?

Tags: uv-image-editor

While trying to figure out why my glass texture was not right I discovered an unexpected behaviour. Ref image:

[image]

I have two cameras in the scene - 1 active and 1 other.
Depending on where my cursor/pointer is when I hit the render key (<kbd>F12</kbd>) I get different results, which are:

A. Cursor over top window = render result as image above. Active camera.

B. Cursor over either bottom window = render image from inactive camera....

Is this normal behaviour and therefore I'm missing something about the UV/Image Editor window that I should be looking into?

Blender 2.76

Note (edit): when I first entered the UV/Image Editor window, the other camera was the active one....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if you lock a camera to a viewport.

To lock a camera to a specific viewport, go to the specific 3D viewport's header and deselect the camera lock button on the right side of the layer buttons. Then press <kbd>N</kbd>, go to "View - Local Camera" and select a different camera.

To deactivate the view-specific camera, just enable the camera lock and the Render will show the view from the active camera again.

[image: lock specific camera to viewport]

**If this answer solves your problem, please vote and mark it as "accepted"**

Comment: After playing with this, I see that when creating another window/viewport, the new window adopts the **Use scene's active camera...** lock status.  If the window camera lock is unlocked then the new window will also be unlocked. Blender seems to default with a locked window. I don't recall unlocking any of the windows... but it's possible I clicked the icon during my newbie struggles.  Thanks @metaphor_set, that's potentially very useful. Accepted :-)